# How to print 25th percentile to 75th percentile value of a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, percentile

I want to print all the values from 25th percentile point to 75th percentile point of a dictionary **without numpy**.

Here is a code snippet I tried.

```
# No Numpy allowed
import pandas as pd
def display_dashboard():
    df=pd.DataFrame({'student':student_list,'marks':marks_list})
    sorte=df.sort_values('marks',ascending=False)
    per_25=round(0.25*len(marks_list))
    per_75=round(0.75*len(marks_list))
    sor=df.sort_values('marks')
    new_dict = {k:v for k, v in sor.items() for v in range(per_25,per_75)}
    print("Students whose marks are between 25th % and 75th % are:-")
    print(new_dict)
```

It gives answer as :-

```
Students whose marks are between 25th % and 75th % in ascending order of marks are:-
{'student': 7, 'marks': 7}
```

I want a dictionary shown where Students and their marks are shown who are in between 25th percentile and 75th percentile of total points in dictionary.

Comment: you know that pandas requires numpy, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` the student list and marks list together for sorting, and use `itertools.islice` to obtain an iterator for entries between the 25th and the 75th percentile, and pass the iterator to the `dict` constructor to build a dict with the student names mapped to their marks:

```
from itertools import islice
from operator import itemgetter
student_list = ['Amy', 'Ben', 'Carl', 'Dan', 'Ean', 'Fab', 'Gal', 'Han']
marks_list = [29, 70, 55, 81, 13, 42, 84, 37]
total = len(marks_list)
print(dict(islice(sorted(zip(student_list, marks_list), key=itemgetter(1, 0), reverse=True), round(0.25 * total), round(0.75 * total))))
```

This outputs:

```
{'Ben': 70, 'Carl': 55, 'Fab': 42, 'Han': 37}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop when you are forming the `dict`, `k` is `student`, `marks` and `v` is index. So, in the `dict` keys ('student`and`marks`) are overridden and the last index value`7` is retained. Hence, you get the result:

```
{'student': 7, 'marks': 7}
```

I have replaced the `for loop` by a `filter` and then converting the `DataFrame` to `dict`:

```
sor = sor.loc[(sor.index >= per_25) & (sor.index <= per_75)]
new_dict = sor.to_dict('records')
```

Here is the modified executable code:

```
import pandas as pd

student_list=['a', 'b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
marks_list=[18, 45, 50, 100, 34, 45, 87, 50, 90, 26]

df=pd.DataFrame({'student':student_list,'marks':marks_list})
sorte=df.sort_values('marks',ascending=False)
per_25=round(0.25*len(marks_list))
per_75=round(0.75*len(marks_list))
sor=df.sort_values('marks')
sor = sor.loc[(sor.index >= per_25) & (sor.index <= per_75)]
new_dict = sor.to_dict('records')
print("Students whose marks are between 25th % and 75th % are:-")
print(new_dict)
```

It produces output:

```
Students whose marks are between 25th % and 75th % are:-
[{'student': 'e', 'marks': 34}, {'student': 'f', 'marks': 45}, {'student': 'c', 'marks': 50}, {'student': 'h', 'marks': 50}, 
{'student': 'g', 'marks': 87}, {'student': 'i', 'marks': 90}, {'student': 'd', 'marks': 100}]
```